# Make Google crawl both redirect source and redirect destination

Tags: google, google-search-console

I designed a Wordpress website that redirects a custom post type to a subdomain. Now my issue is that the destination/redirection end url does not include any SEO meta/descriptions or much information, and i cannot change that. What i can do though is to add all the above to the redirection source. However, Google only crawls the redirected page.

Is there a way to feed Google with information from both pages, source and destination?

Comment: If you are having to redirect to a different site, there is little you can do. Why type of redirect are you using? If you are using the 301 redirect, then you are telling Google the page it came from is permanently gone. You might be able to do something with a 302 but I would guess chances would be slim to none to do anything.

Comment: It's a 301 redirect unfortunately.

Comment: You could try using an iframe for the destination instead of a redirect, and Google would likely use the information from the parent page instead of the child's. However, you'll want to include enough information on the parent's page for Google to index that. That is how most [forwarding with masking](https://www.godaddy.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-domain-forwarding-and-masking-32147) occurs that's offered by many domain registrars. Otherwise, there really is no other way to supply information from both to Google using a redirect.